# EA select Element API

Tags: c#, scripting, add-in, enterprise-architect

I'm creating an Add-in for EA in C# and I'm new in this topic.

I need a method when is selected an element in EA with left click to trigger an event. Now I succeeded to used method `EA_GetMenuItems` for right click, but for left click didn't found any method.

Also when method is triggered I need to know what type of element was selected: a diagram, a block, ..

It will help me also if you have any documentation with EA API C#, I found this documentation, but seems that is old: https://sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/resources/booklets/enterprise_architect_sdk.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the documentation you need is in the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/add-ins___scripting/automation_interface.html), that can be reached by pressing F1 inside EA.

Clicking on an element will trigger the event [EA_OnContextItemChanged](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/add-ins___scripting/ea_oncontextitemchanged.html).

The parameter `ot` gives you the item's type.
You can use one of the `Repository.GetXXXByGUID` methods with the parameter `GUID` to get a hold of the actual object that was selected.

This [example](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack/blob/master/EANavigator/EAAddin.cs) is one of the add-ins I wrote that uses this event.

Comment: When I use override EA_OnContextItemChanged in Visual Studio (like in your example, but in C# language), VS is giving me this error "no suitable method found to override". If I user without override still not triggered when I click on an element (I'm using block element)

Comment: The override, is because I inherit from my addin base class: https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAAddinBase.cs

Comment: The event works. I've used it in a number of add-ins.